# Delay on Backspace on Autocomplete PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jquery-autocomplete

I have a PrimeFaces autocomplete box defined as follows:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Email Addresses to notify:" for="emails" />
<p:autoComplete id="emails" 
                multiple="true" 
                forceSelection="true" 
                value="#{testCaseBean.selectedEmails}" 
                completeMethod="#{testCaseBean.completeEmail}" 
                var="email" 
                itemLabel="#{email}" 
                itemValue="#{email}" 
                queryDelay="1000">                           
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{email}" />
    </p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Everything works as expected, except when I hit backspace when I've been typing. When using backspace, the queryDelay is not applied so it queries immediately. Is there a way around this?

Comment: PrimeFaces does, afaik, not use jquery-autocomplete. And please try PF 10.7

Comment: And there is always the source. Very easy to inspect and see if there is a workaround/fix

Comment: @Kukeltje What is PF 10.7 ? Is it 5.2.10.7 ?

Comment: No, it is attempt to make the OP think about versions and relevance of version info, so we are not gosthunting somethig that e.g. is already fixed in the latest release.

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry I wasn't clear about my PF version in my post. I am using the latest version of PrimeFaces. I realize that it is possible to examine the source and attempt to find a fix, but I am not experienced with javascript and was hoping somebody has had this issue before that could suggest a solution. Just because it is "Very easy to inspect" the code, does not mean it's easy to find a solution.